# Multiprocessing - processes appear not to be executing in parallel

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm very new to multiprocessing so I'm likely doing something really dumb. So the situation in a nutshell:

- I have a GUI app that performs multiple lengthy calculations in the background.
- Since it's a GUI app, the wrapper method that does all calculations uses `threading` to prevent window from hanging:

```py
    def _run_calc(self):
        """
        Run data processing in a separate thread to prevent the main
        window from freezing.
        """

        t = threading.Thread(target=self._process_data)
        t.start()
```

- Inside this thread, further down the line the wrapper method that runs all individual calculations is using multiprocessing:

```py
    def _calculate_components(self):
        processes = []

        if self.mineralogy.get():
            self.minerals = self._get_mineralogy_components()
            miner_worker = Process(target=self.calculate_mineralogy())
            processes.append(miner_worker)
        if self.porosity.get():
            porosity_worker = Process(target=self.calculate_porosity())
            processes.append(porosity_worker)
        if self.poi.get():
            poi_worker = Process(target=self.calculate_poi())
            processes.append(poi_worker)
        if self.water_table.get():
            owt_worker = Process(target=self.calculate_owt())
            processes.append(owt_worker)

        for i in processes:
            i.start()

        for i in processes:
            i.join()

        self._add_components_to_data()
```

- Now the problem is that based on console output processes get executed one after another, not concurrently.
- Also without using multiprocessing a run on a test data takes 35 seconds and 47 with multiprocessing, which, of course defeats the whole purpoise.

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something here and doing something completely wrong. How to make processes run in parallel?

Comment: Don't use `()` at the end of `target=xxx`

Comment: You did it correctly in `threading.Thread()`, but got it wrong in `Process()`

Comment: Ouch! Rookie mistake!